# onScannedRobot method not being called in Robocode

Tags: java, robocode

I am creating a simple robot in Robocode. I have a function *walls* shown below:

```
public void walls() {
        see = false;
        wallBool = true;
        double maxMove = Math.max(getBattleFieldWidth(), getBattleFieldHeight());
        turnLeft(getHeading() % 90);
        ahead(maxMove);

        see = true;
        turnRight(90);
        turnGunRight((getHeading() - getGunHeading())+ 90);

        while (getEnergy() <= 115) {
            wallBool = true;
            see = true;
            ahead(maxMove);
            see = false;
            turnRight(90);
        }
    }
```

Note that `see` and `wallBool` are variables which have already been declared earlier in my code. In the while loop within the function, I call the `turnRight();` method, which should automatically scan for other robots. However, my code does not run in my `onScannedRobot` function, included below:

```
public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
    System.out.println("check");
    if (see==true) {
        System.out.println("check2");
        scan();
    }

    if (wallBool==true) {
        fire(2);
    }
```

Check is never printed to the console. What's wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I would recommend simplifying your code to just rotating the radar and printing if you get a scan event. Then building back up to what you have here.

Comment: Also if you are trying to shoot at the scanned robot, using the `ScannedRobotEvent` to place your shot. The sample bots' source code is a great place to start.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you have put `import robocode.ScannedRobotEvent;` in the import. Also keep your `public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e)`  just below `public void run()` function in case you have changed the order.

Comment: The order in which you declare functions within an object doesn't matter in Java.